# LibGDX cant find .tsx file

Tags: java, libgdx

Does anyone know why libGdx can't find the .tsx file? I have have tmx tsx and png in the assets folder under the core folder. In the tmx file, I have the source set to the file path for the tsx file. I made the tsx and tmx file with Tiled if that helps.

Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: File not found: Maps in use\tileset_gutter.tsx (Internal)

```
mapLoader = new TmxMapLoader();
    map = mapLoader.load("level1V2.tmx");
    renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map);
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't qualify the file reference then it assumes the root folder to be `assets` in the android project as works with everything.

Howeover, you can get the `FileHandle` of files in the core project with
`Gdx.files.internal("data/...` . (where `data` is a folder in `core/assets` which should be where yours are)

You can switch between how `TmxMapLoader` resolves the files, to delegate the `FileResolver` of `TmxMapLoader` to this internal handler would be.

`new TmxMapHolder(new InternalFileHandleResolver())`
which delegates to the internal storage location.

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/File-handling

Comment: Thanks! That seemed to work.